# Hbase compact process hang for hours

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

[image]

As you can see, the compacting is running more than 6 hours. The load of that machine is more than 10, which is not running other heavy task. That index is made by Phoenix, I do not how to handle it to recover the machine.

Comment: That is your index size?